# Bootstrap navbar collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width, navbar

Im having an issue with my navbar in bootstrap, I've changed the collapse width to make it look better since i have alot of links.
The width I changed to is 1400px but as you can see on the picture below the navbar does not create the scrollable navbar unit you hit 767px in width (as standard)...

I cannot find where I should change to make it work again.

Is there anyone here that had this problem before or that can help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Image to see the problem: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6lX.png)

Comment: Well thanks, but where should I put it?

Comment: in the `navbar` class like `.navbar{height:100%!important;}`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid changing width and in general setting values inside your HTML. You will spend a lot of time to get a good result in a specific browser/screen and when you try to access the result from another device the result may disappoint you.

Bootstrap has been designed and tested to work in several browsers/devices by using only its classes (ex row, span6, well, collapse, ..) inside your tags (div,span, ..) where the values have been set in the bootstrap CSS. So, if you still want to change something, it is better to change the CSS and apply the changes global.

You can try to put some code here. This may help.